# Do we need to use the 'Europe' tag even when discussing just one European country?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This is the specific question I'm referring to:

[What's the cheapest way to purchase data access for my verizon smartphone while traveling in Spain?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-purchase-data-access-for-my-verizon-smartphone-while-t)

But in general, I don't see how the Europe tag is very helpful when applied to just one country in Europe. It would be like tagging a question about the US as "North America". I think the Europe tag is only relevant if the question is talking about travelling between European countries, the Euro, EU visas, and things that apply to a larger area of Europe. A question just about Spain (or any other European country) is not a question related to the topic of Europe.

Just my 2C, thoughts?

Comment: Some enterprising user should document this in the "Europe" tag's wiki so everyone coming across the tag knows what it's for. :)

Comment: Nobody has enough rep to do that yet (2000 is required).

Comment: They just go into a queue for review and approval if your rep is too low -- edit away!

Answer (score 14):

Good plan. Use "Europe" if the question is really about Europe, the continent, not just something that happens to be in Europe.

Comment: Agree, some questions are generic and using a generic tag makes sense.

Answer (score 10):

For sure.  You wouldn't tag 'Northern-America' for a question about San Francisco, or 'Asia' for a question about Sri Lanka.  Well, you're unlikely to, at least :D  And if you tagged 'Australia' for a question about New Zealand, I'll hunt you down ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is "needed" but it certainly doesn't hurt. In fact I would recommend it if you have not used all five tags since it will help put all the "related tags" in the right places since tags cannot have an explicit knowledge of which countries are in each region.

In any case I would definitely not recommend retagging questions to remove such tags.